# Logstash failed to put logs to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to setup ELK environment to analysis my logs.
All of 3 tools are in one server, the ip is **192.168.1.114**
and here's my logstash config:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/usr/local/websrv/tomcat/logs/catalina.out"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
  }
}
```

That works, however, when I changed hosts from **["127.0.0.1:9200"]** to **["192.168.1.114:9200"]**, errors happened. I got below messages from logstash.

> Attempted to send a bulk request to Elasticsearch configured at '["http://192.168.1.114:9200/"]', but Elasticsearch appears to be unreachable or down! {:client_config=>{:hosts=>["http://192.168.1.114:9200/"], :ssl=>nil, :transport_options=>{:socket_timeout=>0, :request_timeout=>0, :proxy=>nil, :ssl=>{}}, :transport_class=>Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::HTTP::Manticore, :logger=>nil, :tracer=>nil, :reload_connections=>false, :retry_on_failure=>false, :reload_on_failure=>false, :randomize_hosts=>false}, :error_message=>"Connection refused", :class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :level=>:error}

Could some one advise? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check Elasticsearch' logs from the node startup. There it should say on which IPs and ports it binded to. If `192.168.1.114` is not there, that's the reason. To fix it you need to specifically bind to that IP: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/modules-network.html#common-network-settings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using ES 2.0, this is because ES [binds to localhost by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_network_changes.html#_bind_to_localhost).

In order to change that, you simply need to change the following settings in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file and restart ES:

```
network.bind_host: 192.168.1.114
```